# Sorting Issue Whiling Trying to Keep Correct Order in batch PNGs

Tags: python, image, sorting, image-processing

I'm trying to create an image sequence of colors to display on a monitor for camera tests and I'm running into an sorting issue.  I'm created a look up table of RGB values, then for each row in the look up table, I created a number of 1280X720 images of that color specified by the frame_dur parameter, then it saves each batch in the working directory '/content/', renames all the files and stores them in a new folder.  The problem is how I am naming and sorting the new files.  I can't figure out how to maintain the correct order so the new 'pictures' folder has the same order of the look up table.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob
import shutil
from google.colab import files

    def color_vid(lut_res,frame_dur,res):
      x = np.linspace(0,255,lut_res)
      y = np.linspace(0,255,lut_res)
      z = np.linspace(0,255,lut_res)
      xv,yv,zv = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
      LUT = np.array([zv.flatten(),xv.flatten(),yv.flatten()]).T
    
      ones_image = np.ones((res +(3,)))
      
      for el in range(LUT.shape[0]):
        color_frame = ones_image * LUT[el]
        for i in range(frame_dur):
          im = Image.fromarray(color_frame.astype('uint8'),'RGB')
          im.save( 'row_' + str(el) + 'frame_' + str(i) + ".png" )
      
      for count, filename in enumerate(sorted(glob.glob1("/content/","*.png"))): 
            dst ="picture" +'.' + str(count) + ".png"
            src ='/content/'+ filename 
            dst ='/content/'+ dst 
            os.rename(src, dst) 
      os.mkdir('pictures')
      for filename in glob.glob1("/content/","*.png"):
        source = '/content/' + filename
        destination = '/content/pictures/' + filename
        shutil.move(source, destination)  
      !zip -r /content/color_vid + '_lut_res_' + str(lut_res) +.zip /content/pictures
      files.download("/content/color_vid.zip")
```

Comment: Files in a folder don't have an inherent ordering, but I think I see what you mean. If you want to be able to reproduce the same order you got when you enumerated the source files alphabetically, then I think it's easiest to just prepend the original file's base name onto those destination filenames. If for some reason you can't do that, then you can at least get the same ordering during the program lifetime by adding each destination file to a List as you create them.

Comment: @Noah This seemed to work! Thanks for the tip